# Script Python (boto3) AWS para crear una instancia con recursos de CPU y RAM custom

Tags: python, aws, instancias

¿Es posible crear un Script Python (boto3) AWS para crear una instancia con recursos de CPU y RAM custom y no utilizar los clásicos "Instance Type"?

Comment: Respuesta corta NO. AWS no es una tienda de informática donde puedas encargar un equipo personalizado. AWS te ofrece una serie de máquinas catalogadas en base al InstanceType y es lo que hay. En cualquier caso, tienes tantos tipos distintos que raro es que ninguno se adapte a tus necesidades. Por otro lado, piensa que con la cantidad de servicios diferentes que hay en AWS, el uso de instancias EC2 podría no llegar a ser necesario